# Android Studio Project Directory Preview

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

Why is my Flutter project Opening in Android Studio like the directory view?

[image]

in this case when I am trying to add Flutter SDK then it's not work.

but I open another project which is a view directory like the below picture. so how can I change the above project directory view as like the below picture?

[image]

I tried from android studio menu settings but didn't get a better solution as well as I search online but didn't get any clue

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are correctly installed plugins for the Flutter project.

**Follow these steps to check whether plugins are installed or not:**

- On the welcome screen, Go to the **Plugins** section.
- Check the **Installed** segment, if not found the required plugins follow the next step.
- Search & Install **Flutter** & **Dart** Plugins.
- Now open the project, it will work.

Here is the snapshot of the welcome screen:
[image: Plugins]

Comment: thank you, the problem was in my project name of the directory. I have changed the project name and my project directory was into another directory and i was trying to run the project directory by moving from the main directory. so finally i have again moved the project folder into previous folder. not it works